# How to change the ImageView size at runtime within FrameLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

I have one ImageView inside FrameLayout. I  am increasing the size of FrameLayout programmatically but ImageView size is not changing. I have set the ImageView paramas as MatchParent. Please Help me how to increase the size of image within frameLayout?

here I have added the image into FrameLayout:

```
img_pinch=new ImageView(getApplication());
img_pinch.setImageBitmap(m_bitmap);
img_pinch.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

FrameLayout fm=new FrameLayout(getApplication());
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400,300);

fm.addView(img_pinch,params);
```

below is the code to change the size of frameLayout:

```
int x = (int) temp_img_logo.getWidth();
int y = (int) temp_img_logo.getHeight();

temp_img_logo.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(x+5,y+5,(int)temp_img_logo.getX(),(int)temp_img_logo.getY()));

temp_img_logo.invalidate();
```

temp_img_logo is the instance of FrameLayout.

Comment: Thanks @DavidJhons for your quick response. I have post the code please check it and guide me how to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-assign the imageview in  order to increase the size accordingly , Try this,

At the begining ,

```
img_pinch=new ImageView(getApplication());
img_pinch.setImageBitmap(m_bitmap);
img_pinch.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

FrameLayout fm=new FrameLayout(getApplication());
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400,300);
fm.addView(img_pinch,params);
```

When you need to increase the size of frame layout ,

```
temp_img_logo .removeAllViews();

temp_img_logo .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(400, 400)); // 400 will be use as example
img_pinch.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
temp_img_logo .addView(img_pinch);
temp_img_logo .invalidate();
```